# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nombre')

Tags: node.js, express

I have set all the routes within the same file but when I migrate them to another folder to clean the code the console throws an error, error that was not there when I had all the code in the same file.

```
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const passport = require('passport');
const {Strategy} = require('passport-local')

const LocalStrategy = Strategy;


const app = express();
const usuariosDB= ['UsuariosDB']
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', './views')
app.use(express.static('./public'))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())
// app.use('/', router)
app.use(session({
    secret: '123456788!"#$%&/)(',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    /* cookie:{
        maxAge: 60000
    } */
}))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.redirect('/login')
})

 app.get('/login', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('login')
}) 


app.get('/login-error', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('login-error')
})
app.get('/index', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index', {titulo: "PRUEBAS"})
}) 

 app.get('/registro', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('registro')
})

app.get('/registro-error', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('registro-error')
})

app.get('/datos', (req, res)=>{
    if(req.session.nombre){
        req.session.contador++
        const datosUsuario = usuariosDB.find(element => {return element.nombre == req.session.nombre})
        res.render('datos', {
            datos: datosUsuario,
            contador: req.session.contador
        })

    }

})

app.get('/logout', (req, res)=>{
    req.session.destroy(err=>{
        if(err) return res.json({error: err})
        res.redirect('/login')
    })
})

app.post('/registro', (req, res)=>{
    const {nombre, password, direccion} = req.body
    
    const usuario = usuariosDB.find(element => element.nombre == nombre)

   if(!usuario){
       usuariosDB.push({nombre,password, direccion})
       console.log(usuariosDB)
       res.redirect('/login')
   }else{
       console.log('existe')
       res.redirect('/login')
   }
    
})

app.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
    const {nombre, password} = req.body
    const existeUser = usuariosDB.find(element => element.nombre == nombre)

   if(existeUser){
      req.session.nombre = nombre
      req.session.contador= 0
      res.redirect('/datos') 
   }else{
       console.log('credenciales incorrectas')
       res.redirect('/login-error')
   }
   
})

const PORT = 8080
const server = app.listen(PORT, ()=>console.log(`Listening port ${PORT}`))
server.on('error', error=>{
    console.log(`error on the server ${error}`)
})
```

When I create routes and controller for the app is when I have the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nombre')
```

The error line is `\controller\appController.js:18:26`. The migrated code is the same and I haven't modified anything, this error appears when I try to log in.

```
 exports.getLogin = (req, res)=>{
    res.render('login')
}

exports.postLogin = (req, res)=>{
    const {nombre, password} = req.body;


    const existeUsuario = usuariosDB.find(usuario => usuario.nombre == nombre && usuario.password == password);

    console.log(existeUsuario);
    if (!existeUsuario) {
        console.log('credenciales incorrectas')
        res.redirect('/login-error')
    } else {
      req.session.nombre = nombre
      req.session.contador = 0
      
      res.redirect('/datos')
    }
}

exports.getRegistro = (req, res)=>{
    res.render('registro')
}

exports.postRegistro = (req, res)=>{
    const {nombre, password, direccion} = req.body
    
    const usuario = usuariosDB.find(element => element.nombre == nombre)

   if(!usuario){
       usuariosDB.push({nombre,password, direccion})
       console.log(usuariosDB)
       res.redirect('/login')
   }else{
       console.log('existe')
       res.redirect('/login')
   }    
}

exports.getLoginError = (req, res)=>{
    res.render('login-error')
}
```

and the routes are

```
const Controller = require('../controller/appController.js')
const router = express.Router();

router
    .route('/login')
    .get(Controller.getLogin)
    .post(Controller.postLogin)

router
    .route('/login-error')
    .get(Controller.getLoginError)

router
    .route('/registro')
    .get(Controller.getRegistro)
    .post(Controller.postRegistro)

router
    .route('/datos')
    .get(Controller.getDatos)

router
    .route('/logout')
    .get(Controller.getLogout)


module.exports= router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello tried looking at your code this is my option

```
app.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
    const {nombre, password} = req.body
    const existeUser = usuariosDB.find(element => element.nombre == nombre)

   if(existeUser){
      req.session.nombre = nombre
      req.session.contador= 0
      res.redirect('/datos') 
   }else{
       console.log('credenciales incorrectas')
       res.redirect('/login-error')
   }
```

This endpoint could be throwing that error because property `nombre` does not exist on the session object.

So technically your suing a dot`.` operator on an element that does not exist on the object.

Try logging the session object and see if `nombre` property exists there

Comment: When I run the server the applications works well. The issue starts when I migrate the code. I've tried what you've recommended but didn't work :(